# I got import error when I tried to import torchvision

Tags: python-3.x, torchvision

When I tried to import torchvision, I got an import error.

I googled this problem but found nothing except that the problem may be in Cython. StackOverflow search didn't found anything either. How can I solve this?

`Torchvision version is 0.3.0.`

```
import torchvision
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/home/ai/PycharmProjects/untitled/TRANSFER.py", line 4, in 
>           import torchvision
>       File "/home/ai/anaconda3/envs/reinforcement/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torchvision/**init**.py",
>   line 1, in 
>           from torchvision import models
>       File "/home/ai/anaconda3/envs/reinforcement/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torchvision/models/**init**.py",
>   line 11, in 
>           from . import detection
>       File "/home/ai/anaconda3/envs/reinforcement/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torchvision/models/detection/**init**.py",
>   line 1, in 
>           from .faster_rcnn import *
>       File "/home/ai/anaconda3/envs/reinforcement/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torchvision/models/detection/faster_rcnn.py",
>   line 7, in 
>           from torchvision.ops import misc as misc_nn_ops
>       File "/home/ai/anaconda3/envs/reinforcement/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torchvision/ops/**init**.py",
>   line 1, in 
>           from .boxes import nms, box_iou
>       File "/home/ai/anaconda3/envs/reinforcement/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torchvision/ops/boxes.py",
>   line 2, in 
>           from torchvision import _C
>       ImportError: /home/ai/anaconda3/envs/reinforcement/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torchvision/_C.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so:
>   undefined symbol: _PyThreadState_UncheckedGet

Answer (score 2):

Try this for anaconda:

```
conda install torchvision -c pytorch
```

Using pip:

```
pip install torchvision
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: the problem was in Python 3.5, using Python 3.6 solves problem.